# Conditional rendering of showing / hiding a button - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to hide a menu button if there is . Baiscly if the user is not allowed to see the menu  i receive an empty rol from the token ( basicly `rol : ['']`  , otherwise if it is allowed is `rol : ['_DECLARATION']`. I have tried with a conditional rendering but maybe i am mistaken of my methods that i use. If somebody could give a hand would be very nice .

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                roles: '' 
                     }

async componentDidMount() {
const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
const decodedValue = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Url))
const roles = decodedValue.roles;

 render() {
 const { roles } = this.state
    return (

        { roles 
        ? <Button className="emptyRollButtonDec"/>
        : <Button
          onClick={this.changeActiveComponent
          style= {{
              background: branding.color.colorPrimary,
              color: branding.color.colorTextPrimary
                  }}>
           Declaration
           </Button>
         }
```

I dont know and i dont understand  where i am wrong .

Comment: Try `!roles.length`. `roles` is always defined.

Comment: what is roles ? and are you getting any error ?

Comment: @Andy this is the answer if you want write it down and i can mark it as right . Thank you mate ! Cheers !

Comment: add roles && roles.length===0 in condition.

By this you also check that roles is defined or not

Comment: OP, is there a section of your code missing (in the componentDidMount?)

Comment: @Andy yes it shortened version of my code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `roles` in state as a zero length string. This means that it is defined, not undefined, when you destructure it from the state in your render method. *This* means that you can't use your existing ternary check because `roles ? something : somethingelse` checks to see if `roles` is *defined* or not.

To correct this check the *length* of `roles` instead. If it is zero return the empty button, otherwise show the active button:

```
!roles.length ? showEmptyButton : showActiveButton
```

Comment: Your explanation is not correct.

this is not because of 0 length string is defined. your ans is correct because latest value in roles is array and when we check roles.length than it is true in case of roles is get from url

Comment: There's a section of the OP's code missing - there is no `setState` where `roles` is changed to an array. I'm basing my answer of the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure to update the `roles` state of your component using `setState()`. In the case of your component, you could do that in the `componentDidMount()` life-cycle hook:

```
/* Remove async from method signature as it's not needed */
componentDidMount() {
  const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
  const decodedValue = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Url))
  const roles = decodedValue.roles;

  /* Very important - this will trigger a re-render for your
  component which will ensure that the subsequent render is
  done so with the updated roles state in effect */
  this.setState({ roles : roles });
}
```

Next, you need to ensure that the your conditional role-based rendering is based on boolean represnetation of the `roles` state of the component. As I understand from your question, the empty roles button is shown if the `roles` state is either `''` or `['']`:

```
render() {
    const { roles } = this.state;

    /* If roles is falsey, or first element of roles array 
    is falsey then show empty button */       
    const isEmptyRole = !roles || !roles[0];

    return isEmptyRole ? 
            <Button className="emptyRollButtonDec" /> : 
           (<Button
            onClick={this.changeActiveComponent}
            style={{
                background: branding.color.colorPrimary,
                color: branding.color.colorTextPrimary
            }}>Declaration</Button>) : 
           ;
    }
}
```